# How to select text from random position to the first or last character in gedit?

Tags: gedit

Assuming that this feature is implemented in such an advanced text editor like `gedit` I want to jump from a line `x` with `0 < x < [# lines]` and a column position `y` with `0 <= y <= [length of line]` to the end or the beginning of the document and selected all characters from the random position (defined by `x` and `y`) to the end or beginning.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>(<kbd>Alt</kbd>)<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>Pos1</kbd> (with `()` meaning tried with and without and `/` meaning all combinations left and right of it) with both <kbd>NumLock</kbd> turned on and off, but none worked.

I'm using `gedit` 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Did you try without `Alt`? _i.e._ `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Home`/`End`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl Shift Pos1/End actually does just that for me.
See also Gedit Help (F1) -> "Shortcut keys" -> "Shortcut keys for editing files"

Comment: Seems to be a bug, then.